# Convert javax.mail.Message Email to XML format

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am looking for the open source API if there is any available which can convert javax.mail.Message object to XML specific format or some sample code if there is any already exist ?

Please let me know if you know any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've always done it is by using the DOM parser. Message provides methods to grab every part of the mail (recipients, body, sender...). With that, you can just create your Elements and Attributes and you should be sorted. As far as I'm aware, there is not library that will do that for you.